# Rspec view testing with capybara and rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, rspec, capybara, matcher

I really like the way RSpec is able to separate controller and view tests but have some problems with getting capybara matchers to work in a view test. What i basically try to achieve is sth like this:

```
describe "some page" do
  it "should render with lots of stuff" do
    assign ..
    render
    rendered.should have_button ('Any button') #or any capybara matcher, really
  end
end
```

I've seen some posts on the net showing how to configure capybara and rails3 to work smoothly with cucumber or rspec controller tests, but this is not really what I want - that is, testing the views at the lowest level possible.

Also if there's another way to do this (not requiring lots of custom code, couse I know i could write some matchers that extract given selectors from rendered using nokogiri or whatever tool suitable) that'd be great too - using capybara is not a requirement.

Answer (score 18):

There is now an option to use Capybara matchers (without Webrat baggage) when testing controllers (and views too). I'm using it this way:

```
describe GlobalizeTranslationsController do

  render_views
  let(:page) { Capybara::Node::Simple.new(@response.body) }

  describe "PUT :update" do
    before do
      put :update
    end

    it "displays a flash notice" do
      page.should have_selector('p.notice')
    end

  end

end
```

Full code:

- https://github.com/Exvo/exvo_globalize/blob/master/spec/controllers/globalize_translations_controller_spec.rb

References:

- http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/8087279685/use-capybara-on-any-html-fragment-or-page
- http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2010/09/19/cucumber-switching-from-webrat-to-capybara/
- http://trevorturk.com/2010/12/22/using-capybara-without-cucumber-in-rails-3

Comment: I really don't recommend testing controllers like that. Using your example, that kind of test fits better on the view level.

Comment: Fully agree! Controller specs should only test controller logic, not the views. If you want to test views create requests/features specs (using Capybara + Poltergeist or capybara-webkit).

Comment: This is a perfect case for view specs: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-0/docs/view-specs/view-spec

Answer (score 11):

Capybara currently does not work with view specs (there are plans to make it work in the future). The simplest answer is to just add `gem 'webrat'` to the Gemfile and you're basically set. You might not have `have_button` but you'll have `have_selector`, `have_tag` and similar available.

Btw: as far as I know capybara and webrat can co-exist in one project.

Comment: Has anyone had any problems with Capybara matchers leaking into view tests?

Comment: Just a note for anyone stumbling by these days:  Capybara does support view specs now:  https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/README.md#using-capybara-with-rspec

Answer (score 10):

Slightly simpler than Pawel's answer, but the gist is the same; the following works for me with rails 3.1.0, rspec 2.6.0, capybara 1.1.1:

```
page = Capybara::Node::Simple.new( rendered )
page.should have_content( "blah" )
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't call capybara's methods on `rendered`, that's just a string. You can use [Capybara's string method](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara.string) though to wrap `rendered` in a Capybara node. Then, you can call Capybara's methods on that node:

```
describe "some page" do
  it "should render with lots of stuff" do
    assign ..
    render
    Capybara.string(rendered).should have_button('Any button')
  end
end
```

For more information, check out this post:

http://www.tamingthemindmonkey.com/2011/11/07/capybara-matchers-and-scoping-in-view-specs

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of this page, in the "Webrat and Capybara" section, it looks like Capybara is unsupported for rspec view specs

http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails

Comment: Correct.  If you use Capybara's default driver (`:rack_test`), writing your view tests as "request tests" with Capybara should still give you reasonably good performance, by the way.  It's how I essentially test my views.  You just don't get to use `assign`, so you have a little less control compared to "real" view tests.

Answer (score 1):

Updating this old question as things have changed since most of the other answers were added:

**Capybara now does support view specs** (out of the box) and this is documented on [Capybara's master branch](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/README.md#using-capybara-with-rspec).

To quote the docs:

Finally, Capybara matchers are supported in view specs:

```
RSpec.describe "todos/show.html.erb", type: :view do
  it "displays the todo title" do
    assign :todo, Todo.new(title: "Buy milk")

    render

    expect(rendered).to have_css("header h1", text: "Buy milk")
  end
end
```

Support for these without additional `let(:page)` style code appears to have been added in an earlier version.  (It's working for me in capybara 2.4.4 and 2.2).
Note also that only a limited subset of matchers are supported; however you can gain more functionality by using [Capybara.string](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara#string-class_method); ex:

```
expect(Capybara.string(rendered).first('td')).to have_no_content 'Tom Riddle'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use capybara syntax

```
describe "some page" do 
  it 'should render hello with name' do
    assign(:user, double("User", first_name: "John"))
    render
    expect(rendered).to have_content("Hello John")
  end
end
```