# Using both webrat and capybara together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, capybara, webrat

I've been using Capybara for integration/request testing, but have only just realised I can't do view testing with it.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706370/rspec-view-testing-with-capybara-and-rails3) suggests Webrat and Capybara can be used in tandem; but the [RSpec docs](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-6/file/readme) suggest one must choose between the two.  [Here's another github thread](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/302) that suggests webrat can be used for views and capybara for integration.

I've found that if I include Webrat in my gemfile, I can use webrat for views with no problem, but my capybara-styled integration tests no longer work.  Specifically, I get an error with the following simple example:

```
it "should have a Home page at '/'" do
  visit '/'
  page.should have_selector('title', :content => "Home page")
end
```

I get the error:

```
No response yet. Request a page first.
```

What's the best way (if any?) to get webrat and capybara to like eachother?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I must say though, a month ago I was using the together on a different project no problem. Doesn't seem to work anymore. One other thing, I tried updating capybara to 1.0.0.beta1. I just get different error messages though.

Comment: I've given up and just started using capybara without webrat.  I now test my views in a roundabout way using capybara's integration testing methods - definitely not ideal but will do.  I'm sure there is a way to get them working together though, let's hope someone comes a long with a good answer!

Comment: Quick question, how are you testing put and delete actions with capybara in controllers? It seems to only have a 'visit' action which can only issue GET requests?

Comment: @duckyfuzz: Try something like visit whatever_path, :put, {'key' => 'value'} and
visit whatever_path, :delete

Comment: @Tyler: I haven't had a chance to test your suggestion yet but I have an open question on this issue from a while ago so maybe you might like to post your suggestion there and if I can get it to work I'll accept your answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908216/how-do-i-use-capybara-get-show-post-put-in-controller-tests

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's generally no reason to use both Webrat and Capybara. Pick one (probably Capybara). View tests are a bad idea and shouldn't be necessary in general; usually your integration tests should cover that ground.

In other words, fix your testing strategy and the problem will go away.

Comment: Also, try to avoid using RSpec for user-facing testing. Cucumber is much better at this.

Answer (score 6):

In general, I agree with Marnen about "just pick one of them, probably Capybara", but one possible reason to use both of them is gradual migration.

Say, you have a large test suite and you're migrating it to Capybara, but you'd like to let some of your old tests to stay "Webrat-driven" for some time.

Although, I didn't find ideal solution for this case, here's what I did:

```
# features/support/env.rb
...
if ENV['WITH_WEBRAT'].nil?
    require 'capybara/rails'
    require 'capybara/cucumber'
    ...
else
    require 'webrat'
    ...
end
...

# config/cucumber.yml
...
default: --profile capybara
capybara: <% std_opts %> --tags ~@webrat features
webrat:   <% std_opts %> --tags @webrat features WITH_WEBRAT=1
...

# features/webrat.feature
@webrat
...

# features/capybara.feature
...
```

Now, you can do `cucumber` to run your capybara-only test suite or `cucumber -p webrat` for your legacy Webrat features.

Not ideal, but it worked for me.